# React-Router: No Not Found Route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Consider the following:

```
var AppRoutes = [
    <Route handler={App} someProp="defaultProp">
        <Route path="/" handler={Page} />
    </Route>,

    <Route  handler={App} someProp="defaultProp">
        <Route path="/" handler={Header} >
            <Route path="/withheader" handler={Page} />
        </Route>
    </Route>,

    <Route handler={App} someProp="defaultProp">
        <Route path=":area" handler={Area} />
        <Route path=":area/:city" handler={Area} />
        <Route path=":area/:city/:locale" handler={Area} />
        <Route path=":area/:city/:locale/:type" handler={Area} />
    </Route>
];
```

I have an App Template, a HeaderTemplate, and Parameterized set of routes with the same handler (within App template).  I want to be able to serve 404 routes when something is not found.  For example, /CA/SanFrancisco should be found and handled by Area, whereas /SanFranciscoz should 404.

Here's how I quickly test the routes.

```
['', '/', '/withheader', '/SanFranciscoz', '/ca', '/CA', '/CA/SanFrancisco', '/CA/SanFrancisco/LowerHaight', '/CA/SanFrancisco/LowerHaight/condo'].forEach(function(path){
    Router.run(AppRoutes, path, function(Handler, state){
        var output = React.renderToString(<Handler/>);
        console.log(output, '\n');
    });
});
```

The problem is /SanFranciscoz is always being handled by the Area page, but I want it to 404.  Also, if I add a NotFoundRoute to the first route configuration, all the Area pages 404.

```
<Route handler={App} someProp="defaultProp">
    <Route path="/" handler={Page} />
    <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFound} />
</Route>,
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a gist that can be downloaded and experimented on.

https://gist.github.com/adjavaherian/aa48e78279acddc25315

Comment: For future reference for people who end up to this question, apart from the right answer below, have a read at [this article](https://medium.com/@leonardobrunolima/react-tips-handling-404-pages-24d27191a8dd). I came across it earlier and I think that person explains it perfectly.

Answer (score 370, accepted):

DefaultRoute and NotFoundRoute were removed in react-router 1.0.0.

I'd like to emphasize that the default route with the asterisk **has to be last** in the current hierarchy level to work. Otherwise it will override all other routes that appear after it in the tree because it's first and matches every path.

**For react-router 1, 2 and 3**

If you want to display a 404 and **keep the path** (Same functionality as NotFoundRoute)

```
<Route path='*' exact={true} component={My404Component} />
```

If you want to display a 404 page but **change the url** (Same functionality as DefaultRoute)

```
<Route path='/404' component={My404Component} />
<Redirect from='*' to='/404' />
```

Example with multiple levels:

```
<Route path='/' component={Layout} />
    <IndexRoute component={MyComponent} />
    <Route path='/users' component={MyComponent}>
        <Route path='user/:id' component={MyComponent} />
        <Route path='*' component={UsersNotFound} />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/settings' component={MyComponent} />
    <Route path='*' exact={true} component={GenericNotFound} />
</Route>
```

**For react-router 4 and 5**

Keep the path

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/users" component={MyComponent} />
    <Route component={GenericNotFound} />
</Switch>
```

Redirect to another route (change url)

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/users" component={MyComponent} />
    <Route path="/404" component={GenericNotFound} />
    <Redirect to="/404" />
</Switch>
```

**The order matters!**

Comment: if you have a redux app how do you do : `<Redirect from='*' to='/home' />` in this syntaxe : `const routes = {
    component: Main,
    childRoutes: [
     { path: '/', component: Home },
    ],
    indexRoute: {
        component: Main,
    },
};`

Comment: if you want to set props for the 404-Compontent use this code:
`<Route render={(props)=> <MyComponent myProp={someVar} {...props} />} />`

Comment: What about a 500 page? Like a page that's supposed to load but the API gives an error. How to show this instead of the page that failed while keeping the route?

Comment: <Redirect to="/404" /> causes Maximum update depth exceed on react-router-dom 5.0.0. Even if page 404 exits, it redirects.

Comment: I dislike using a redirect because it hides the problematic URL from the user. It also requires hitting back twice to return to the previous page.

Comment: @PixMach you could use history.push(/500) in a error handler https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history, or let it throw and harness React Error Boundries for a more global option: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

Comment: Is it safe to assume that `Redirect` will only be rendered if the `Switch` falls through all the routes above it or would it be safer to wrap it in its own catch-all `Route`?

Answer (score 57):

In newer versions of react-router you want to [wrap the routes in a Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match) which only renders the first matched component. Otherwise you would see multiple components rendered.

For example:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  browserHistory,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './app/App';
import Welcome from './app/Welcome';
import NotFound from './app/NotFound';

const Root = () => (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
      <Route path="/welcome" component={Welcome}/>
      <Route component={NotFound}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: You don't need to include `path="*"` on the NotFound Route. Omitting `path` will cause the Route to always match.

Comment: For people coming in late, @chipit24 is right, to avoid confusion just omit the ```path``` entirely for unknown routes

Answer (score 22):

With the new version of React Router (using 2.0.1 now), you can use an asterisk as a path to route all 'other paths'.

So it would look like this:

```
<Route route="/" component={App}>
    <Route path=":area" component={Area}>
        <Route path=":city" component={City} />
        <Route path=":more-stuff" component={MoreStuff} />    
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" component={NotFoundRoute} />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 16):

**For those who are using react router v6**

Redirect component has been removed from the react-router version 6.
For `react-router-dom` v6, simply replace `Redirect` with `Navigate`

[Migrating up to v6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5)

`npm install react-router-dom@6`

```
import {Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/404" element={<div>Choose the correct path</div>} />
                <Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/404" />} />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 14):

**This answer is for react-router-4.**
You can wrap all the routes in Switch block, which functions just like the switch-case expression, and renders the component with the first matched route. eg)

```
<Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={home}/>
      <Route path="/home" component={home}/>
      <Route component={GenericNotFound}/> {/* The Default not found component */}
</Switch>
```

When to use `exact`

Without exact:

```
<Route path='/home'
       component = {Home} />

{/* This will also work for cases like https://<domain>/home/anyvalue. */}
```

With exact:

```
<Route exact path='/home'
       component = {Home} />

{/* 
     This will NOT work for cases like https://<domain>/home/anyvalue. 
     Only for https://<url>/home and https://<domain>/home/
*/}
```

Now if you are accepting routing parameters, and if it turns out incorrect, you can handle it in the target component itself. eg)

```
<Route exact path='/user/:email'
       render = { (props) => <ProfilePage {...props} user={this.state.user} />} />
```

Now in ProfilePage.js

```
if(this.props.match.params.email != desiredValue)
{
   <Redirect to="/notFound" component = {GenericNotFound}/>
   //Or you can show some other component here itself.
}
```

For more details you can go through this code:

[App.js](https://github.com/nyctophiliacme/Chat-App/blob/master/client/src/App.js)

[ProfilePage.js](https://github.com/nyctophiliacme/Chat-App/blob/master/client/src/ProfilePage.js)

Answer (score 8):

According to the [documentation](https://rackt.github.io/react-router/#NotFoundRoute), the route *was* found, even though the resource wasn't.

> **Note**: This is not intended to be used for when a resource is not found. There is a difference between the router not finding a matched path and a valid URL that results in a resource not being found. The url courses/123 is a valid url and results in a matched route, therefore it was "found" as far as routing is concerned. Then, if we fetch some data and discover that the course 123 does not exist, we do not want to transition to a new route. Just like on the server, you go ahead and serve the url but render different UI (and use a different status code). You shouldn't ever try to transition to a NotFoundRoute.

So, you could always add a line in the `Router.run()` before `React.render()` to check if the resource is valid. Just pass a prop down to the component or override the `Handler` component with a custom one to display the NotFound view.

Comment: thanks @brad, you're right, you have to handle this with the component and or override the handler before router.run

Comment: NotFound was deprecated https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/releases/tag/v1.0.0, now use `<Route path="*" to="/dest" />` or `<Redirect from="*" to="/dest" />` as the last sub route to match, I believe

Answer (score 8):

The above answers are correct and for react 5 before. In React v6, `Switch` no longer exists. This solution is for react **v6**:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";

...

<Router>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <Link to="t1">component1</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
            <Link to="t2">component2</Link>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <Routes>
        <Route path="/t1" exact element={<Component1/>}/>
        <Route path="/t2" exact element={<Component2/>}/>
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound/>}/>
    </Routes>

</Router>
```

Answer (score 6):

I just had a quick look at your example, but if i understood it the right way you're trying to add 404 routes to dynamic segments. I had the same issue a couple of days ago, found [#458](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/458) and [#1103](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1103) and ended up with a hand made check within the render function:

```
if (!place) return <NotFound />;
```

hope that helps!

Comment: thanks @jorn, I think you're right, this seems only addressable from the component level

Comment: @Jorn - so your saying the uri's we need to verify locally using some scripts then return ```<NotFound>``` . is that right ?

Answer (score 5):

**React Router v6**

Live Demo: [Redirect Default or 404 Routes with React Router](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/redirect-routes-with-react-router)

Example code:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="users" element={<Users />} />
    <Route path="posts" element={<Posts />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

To redirect and navigate to one of our chosen routes, we can use `<Navigate>` component from React Router. Now we can declare below our route configuration the case for empty routes, like this:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="users" element={<Users />} />
    <Route path="posts" element={<Posts />} />
    <Route path="" element={<Navigate to="/users" />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue, instead of using `*` wild identifier or Default Switch Component. We can simply just use Route Component without defining path.

example:

```
<Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={Root} />
      <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
      <Route component={NotFoundPage} /> 
// Default Component To load If none  of the path matches.
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" Component={Exercises} />
        <Route path="exercise/new" Component={ExerciseNew} />
        <Route path="*" Component={NotFound}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```