# How do I Serve a 404 page using firebase hosting for a React SPA?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-router, firebase-hosting

I am currently using firebase hosting for my single page React application. I have also added a ***404.html*** page to my public directory. My assumption was that this page would get served if a user enter an url that is not in my routes(using react-router), but there is no way for firebase to know if an url is valid or not, or is there. Currently if I enter something random after the / of my main app url the page just shows blank.  Is this something i need to account for within my React app, if so HOW?

Comment: I expect that your firebase.json contains a `"source": "**"` rewrite, which means that you're rewriting all URLs to your main page. Firebase Hosting has no knowledge that you're using react-router, so it cannot detect an unmatched route. So you'll have to add a default/catchall route to your client-side react-router configuration. This looks promising: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128978/react-router-no-not-found-route

Comment: Any code you can share as to how your router is setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let the React Router take care of serving a 404 page on the client side. This is how you can setup:

```
var NotFound = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (<h1>Page Not Found</h1>);
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <Route path="first" component={SomeComponent}/>
                <Route path="second" component={SomeOtherComponent}/>
                <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    }

});
```

Note that the catch all route (*) should be the last so that React Router can try all others and finally get to this.

[Here's](http://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/guides/NotFound.html) a nice article that explains this.

Comment: But be aware that this will not respond with HTTP 404. If you need a correct HTTP status code, you'll have to use fine tuned rewrite rules as suggested by Michael Bleigh

Answer (score 6):

You can partially solve this using `firebase.json` configuration, but because Firebase Hosting only serves up static content you'll have to handle some of the logic in your JavaScript. A simple catch-all looks like:

```
{
  "hosting":{
    "rewrites":[{"source":"**","destination":"/index.html"}]
  }
}
```

However, you can create more specific rewrites to match your application's route structure, for instance:

```
{
  "hosting":{
    "rewrites":[
      {"source":"/users/*","destination":"/index.html"},
      {"source":"/account","destination":"/index.html"},
      {"source":"/posts/*","destination":"/index.html"},
    ]
  }
}
```

In the above example, `/users/foo` would route to `/index.html` but `/unknown/url` would route to `404.html`.

The above gets you part of the way there, but doesn't know about your actual application data. If `/users/foo` is not a valid username, you'll need to display a not found message using JavaScript in `/index.html`.