# React router v4, Redirect unknown routes to home/root page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Is there an easy way to redirect all unknown routes to home page?

I am using the nested route structure where (nested) routes lives inside the components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[React-Router: No Not Found Route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128978/react-router-no-not-found-route)

For react-router v4

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={MyComponent} />
  <Route component={HomePage} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: I am not using Switch, I am using the nested routes, where child routes will be in its parent component.