# page gets blank if someone type unknown url with trailing slashes one after the other

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, router, react-router-redux

if url is typed http://anyhost.com/home, it is working fine,but if typed http://anyhost.com/home/unknown/unknown, it gives me blank page and, in dev tools it is showing me that index.html file in public folder is not able to find app.js,please find the below screenshot for error.

[image]

I dont know this is an `react router` problem or need to do setting in `server config`,please help me

using react router
`"react-router": "^4.2.0","react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",`

Comment: Do you have an otherwise route aka not found aka 404? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128978/react-router-no-not-found-route

Comment: What are you using in server side express/koa ??. can you also paste your server side code where you server this html.

Comment: @vikramaditya,@sten-muchow i am using nginx, please check this gist https://gist.github.com/tapandave08/6636fd26e1c5a25bd0e6667805c6dbee

Comment: in your html file change this line from `<script src="assets/app.js"></script>` to `<script src="/assets/app.js"></script>`. make sure assets folder is located in the same level from where you are running nginx server.

Comment: Also make sure you are sending the same html file from nginx server on all http requests. your nginx.conf file should be something like this..
`server {
   root /path/to/app-folder/;
   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /public.html;
   }
} 
`

Comment: @vikramaditya thanks '/assets/app.js, ' i was searching for this thing from many days it worked