# Is there a way to define default route (if no one match) in react-router-redux@5.0.0

Tags: react-router, react-router-redux

Im using react-router-redux@5.0.0

I have this

```
<Route path='/login' component={ Login } />
<Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
```

Is there a way to define default route as in react-router-redux@4.x.x?

It is also necessary this "default route" does not pass if any other matched.

Because if I will add

```
<Route path='/login' component={ Login } />
<Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
<Route component={ Default } />
```

Default component will be rendered for all routes, including '/login' and '/'

Comment: Yeah. Without setting a path, it would work.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for answer for the same problem but for `react-router-dom` package. The solution was this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/login' component={ Login } />
  <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
  <Route component={ Default } />
</Switch>
```

This way the first Route that matches will be displayed while the rest ignored.

You can import `Switch` together with `Route` like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the following catch-all route after all other routes are defined (optionally leave the path out as stated below):

```
<Route path="*" component={DefaultRoute} />
```

Here's a link to an answer with more details:  [React-Router: No Not Found Route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128978/react-router-no-not-found-route)

Comment: catch all route will be displayed along with matched routes

Comment: Instead of defining a default component, it is also possible to define a custom message
          <Route
            path='*'
            element={
              <div >
                <h2>PAGE NOT FOUND :(</h2>
              </div>
            }
          />

Answer (score 0):

With latest react-router version,

`<Route path='' Componenet={Default}>`

should be changed to,

`<Route path='' element={<Default>}>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In react-router-dom 5, we could do :
 
<Switch>
...
    <Route render={()=> {
      return(<h2 style={{color:'black',marginTop:'70px'}}>Page not found :( </h2>)
    }} />
</Switch>

Is there a way to use a similar syntax in the latest react-router-dom?I am trying the above but it's not working