# How do I redirect when no route is matched?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I want to do something like this where if no route matches I instantly redirect to '/'. With the code below when I hit the path that doesn't exist I get `Nothing was returned from render`

```
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={UnAuth} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/:contentId" component={Content} />
      <Redirect to="/" />
   // <Redirect from='*' to='/' /> doesn't work as well
    </Switch>
```

Comment: I think this has been answered before, you may check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128978/react-router-no-not-found-route

Comment: thanks for the reference. Updated  my post

Comment: can you give an example on which route you need to redirect. As in you code, /:contentId cover all the 1st level of subdirectory of your router.

Comment: on route that doesn't match any previous. I.e user types some hibridish in url like `/fvdsivdskbvdsi`

Comment: <Redirect to="/myComponent " /> should take care of route which are not defined .. If an any rubbish url is entered it would be redirected to myComponent.        <Route exact path="/" component={UnAuth} should be changed ... https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a "catch all route" that will redirect to wherever ("/")

so you will first to create a "catch all" route

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={UnAuth} />
  <PrivateRoute exact path="/:contentId" component={Content} />
  //...all of your routes here

  // this route will catch any route that wasnt matched in previous routes
  <Route component={RedirectToMain}/> 

</Switch>
```

and the component that will get all the routes and redirect:
It will only do redirection to `/` if you want more logic you can just create a class that will handle anything else.

```
const RedirectToMain = _ => {
    return (
        <Redirect to="/" />
    );
}
```

Comment: I have same as you but still same issue `Nothing was returned from render`

Comment: updated my redirect class, maybe I had a syntax error. Please share the code that you have. Share the logs that happen? and what is the "render" that is not called? share everything as I can't really guess what you have in your code.

Comment: this is working now `<Route render={() => <Redirect to="/" />} />`