# How can I redirect from wildcard routes to the home page?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router

I want to redirect from any * route to my home page, because I want to change url to '/'.

I followed this link:

[React-Router: No Not Found Route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128978/react-router-no-not-found-route)

But when I want to change any route path It moves me independently to the url '/'

```
<Route exact path="/" component={MMPStudio} />
<Route exact path="/galeria" component={Gallery} />
<Route exact path="/kontakt" component={Contact} />
<Route exact path="/fotobudka" component={Fotobudka} />
<Route exact path="/jubiler" component={Jubiler} />{" "}
<Route exact path="/fotobudka/kontakt" component={FotobudkaContact} />
<Route exact path="/jubiler/galeria" component={JubilerGallery} />

<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={MMPStudio} />
    <Redirect from="*" to='/' />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your switch should wrap the whole thing:

```
   <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={MMPStudio} />
      <Route exact path="/galeria" component={Gallery} />
      <Route exact path="/kontakt" component={Contact} />
      <Route exact path="/fotobudka" component={Fotobudka} />
      <Route exact path="/jubiler" component={Jubiler} />
      <Route exact path="/fotobudka/kontakt" component={FotobudkaContact} />
      <Route exact path="/jubiler/galeria" component={JubilerGallery} />
      <Redirect from="*" to='/' />
    </Switch>
```

Comment: Yeah it works, but when I redirect with this my logo image is not loading properly, when I change to other url and back to '/' image is loaded properly. I'm getting this error: 'GET http://localhost:3000/fotobudka/logo_studio.png 404 (Not Found)'