# Reactjs after build got not found when refresh in a specific Url

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know maybe this topic is duplicate, but I ask because I failed to try the answer about my problem with the answer I found with the similar topic.

as the title said I want to make my route like **[some-web-link].com/order**, but my problem is the page works fine in localhost or when I first hit my **[some-web-link].com/**, but when I directly type like **[some-web-link].com/order** it failed and return **404 Not Found**. I find it maybe because of my router like some the answer in here:

[how-to-fix-react-page-not-working-after-refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56014528/how-to-fix-react-page-not-working-after-refresh)

[react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually/36623117#36623117)

[react-router-no-not-found-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128978/react-router-no-not-found-route)

but still no luck.

this is my app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Switch, Route, Redirect, BrowserRouter  } from 'react-router-dom';
import { history } from './Helpers';
import { PrivateRoute } from './Components/PrivateRoute';

// Components
import './App.css';
import Homepage from './Components/homepage/homepage';
import Orderpage from './Components/orderpage/orderpage';
import Cart from './Components/cart/cart';
import { Login } from './Components/Login/Login';
import { Signup } from './Components/Signup/Signup';
import { Dashboard } from './Components/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import { Order } from './Components/Order/Order';
import { Product } from './Components/product/product';
import { ProductDetail } from './Components/product/productdetail/productdetail';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
            <Route exact path="/order" component={Orderpage} />
            <Route exact path="/cart" component={Cart} />
            <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
            <Route exact path='/sign-up' component={Signup} />
            {/* <Route exact path='/' render={() => (<Redirect to="/dashboard" />)} />             */}
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}/>
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/user-order' component={Order}/>          
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/products' component={Product}/>          
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/products/product-detail/:id' component={ProductDetail}/>          
            <Route path='*' component={Homepage} />            
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>    
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

you can see that i tried to use redirect or catch-all but still failed. Can someone help me tell where I did wrong?

Comment: it is a webpack config issue not in your code

Comment: It is the same problem. What is the server technology that you are using ? Configure your server such that any request to it will serve the same html file with your app bundle in it to fix this problem.

Comment: Can you add your server code?  This is definitely an issue with how the build is served up, not with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Trying and searching for several days, finally I can solve this problem, this answer is for you who find the same problem with routing behaviour when you tried to klik your link like **[web-url].com/some-page** and find it **404** but you can hit it by hitting your url like **[web-url].com** without any problem, I fix this problem by adding `.htaccess` file inside your `public` folder in `[your-project-name]/public` then your file will have this path such as `[your-project-name]/public/.htaccess` with this 4 line,

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . ./index.html [L]
```

and it works like charm. this line force your link to direct to the root first and after that find the page through your web route so you can fix **404 not Found** problem with this

if someone have any better idea than this, feel free to add my answer about this