# React Router v4 - Redirect and Rendering Issue on Refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

First of all,

- I am NEW to JS and React ( 3 months since I start learning JS ).
- React Router v4 is used ( due to the course's restriction )
- No Redux nor React Hooks used ( I didn't learn these yet )

If a user refreshes the window, it stays on the same address - *I think it's technically the same as when you append keywords(route) on the address bar and push `enter` key* - ( if you don't use `redirect` or anything modifies the route ), which has benefits on particular situations; however, the downside would be my case( *not sure if it's actually true..please let me know if I am wrong* ).

---

#### - I want to achieve three goals,

- 1a. the route path is matched to `keyword` state, which initial state is `cats` and which is the same as the user-input when a user submits an input value
- 2a. when a user refreshes the window, it goes back to initial `componentDidMount` state ( redirect to `/cats` )
- 3a. when a user types an address that does not exist, the 404 error component is rendered

#### - The issue I have to achieve those goals is,

- 1b. If I use `Redirect` to achieve "2a", and then if I type non-existing routes ( such as "/catsasldkja" ), it does not show 404 error component and redirects to `/cats`
- 2b. If I use `Switch` component to achieve "3a", it renders 404 error component as expected; however, it stays on the same address, so when a user is on the `/cats` address and refreshes the window, it works well, but when a user is on other routes(addresses) such as `/dogs` or `/brandon`, it renders the 404 error component: `PageNotFound.js`, because the `keyword` state is rolled back to initial state, which is `cats`, but the path is still on `/brandon` for instance, and the `keyword` state does not match to the route path, `/cats` so it renders 404 component

How can I possibly solve this issue?

Here is my [Git Repo](https://github.com/brandonwie/FS_proj07_React_gallery_app)
and
[Live Link](https://brandonwie-react-galley-app.netlify.com/cats)

Thank you so much for your time in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Router: No Not Found Route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128978/react-router-no-not-found-route)

Comment: Hi @lehm.ro I've already tried and used the method for Router 4, 5, but didn't work. It's different situation than his, because my path is not fixed, it changes according to the keyword state, but thank you so much for additional info.