# React-router doesn't work in my remote environment

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've tried this

[React-Router: No Not Found Route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128978/react-router-no-not-found-route)

at my localhost, it works well. But in the remote server, it doesn’t work.
when I put "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Welcome " directly on browser , 404 always comes out.

Answer (score 1):

Please, post router code snippet and webserver config. I assume the problem is nginx/apache not serving `index.html` properly.

Here i have an example from my working server that serves build version of my react project that uses react-router

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        root /home/full_project_directory/build;
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }
    ...
}
```

The code above catches any path variables and redirects them to index.html, where react-router is able to handle them.