# How to redirect to 404 if particular dynamic page is unavailable in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have multiple routes.
all pages are working fine with displaying 404 page if the URL is not proper.
how to redirect to 404 the page if ordere ID is not available for such dynamic page.

routes

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/Dashboard" component={authGuard(Home)} />
        <Route path="/Shop/Order/:orderID" component={authGuard(Order)} />
        <Route path="/Shop/Shop-orders" component={authGuard(ShopOrders)} />
        <Route path="/Shop/Shop-products" component={authGuard(ShopProducts)} />
        <Route path="/Shop/Product/:productID" component={authGuard(Product)} />
        <Route path="/Shop/Sign-in" component={loggedInGuard(SignIn)} />
        <Route path="/Shop/Shop-profile" component={authGuard(Profile)} />
        <Route exact path="/Shop/Invoice" component={authGuard(Invoice)} />
        <Route path="/Shop/Invoice/:billID" component={authGuard(Bill)} />
        <Route path="" component={PageNotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </App>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: check in componentDidMount if paramId is valid, if not then redirect to 404

Comment: how do I do that?
with whom should I compare the param value with? @MikołajRutecki

Comment: Have you even tried anything?? Share your code.

Comment: `allOrdersData.forEach(el => {
      if (el === []) {
        return  <PageNotFound />
      }
    })`

Answer (score 0):

check this answer I think it might help you

[React-Router: No Not Found Route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128978/react-router-no-not-found-route)

but it is something like this

```
   <Switch>
    <Route path="/404" component={PageNotFound} />
    <Redirect to="/404" />
   </Switch>
```

Comment: Nope didn't work
It still renders orders page without data .

Comment: That's another problem. I think that you want to render otder page with data.