# React Router Not Showing 'Not Found' Page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I can't seem to get my NotFound component to render. Whenever I type in some random characters in the url (ex: 'localhost:3000/asdfasdfasdfasdf'), the browser actually directs to my Topics component, with no content.

Here is how I have the routes set up:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
         <Route exact path='/' component={HomepageLayout} />  
         <Route exact path='/:topic' component={Topic} />  
         <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
 }

export default App;
```

I've also tried not specifying a path, as some have advised, but this didn't work either:

```
<Route component={NotFound} />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Router: No Not Found Route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128978/react-router-no-not-found-route)

Comment: add complate code app.js.

Comment: i would modify your /:topic route to /topic/:topic then it should work as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work as you are mentioning in the second route as any value can hold as /:topic, this route will get displayed when you add like this. Because, **any segment that starts with a colon will be treated as a parameter**. So the * route will not get displayed at any case!