# React Router Dom- Handling 404 Routes in React (Nested routers)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Hello I have the following logic, my routers wrapped with div`s

```
 render() {
    return (<div id={'container'} className={this.state.mode} >


                <div id='buyers'>
                   <NavBar />
                    <Route path='/buy/' render={()=><BuyersBuy />} /> 
                    <Route path='/refund/:id?' render={()=><BuyersRefund />} />
                    <Route path='/download/:id?' render={()=><BuyersDownload />} />
                    ...(Around 18 Routes for Buyers)
                </div>

                //Sellers Routers
                 <div id='dashboard'>
                    {this.state.pathname === '/private' && <TopNavBarSellers />}
                    {this.state.pathname === '/private' && <LeftNavBarSellers />}
                    <Route path='/dashbaord/profile' render={()=><SellersDash />} /> 
                    (4 routers more)
                </div>
```

And so according to that I wanted to create not found page

I tried to wrap a `Switch` but it doesn't work because there are div`s inside of it.

Comment: Where is/are the nested `Router`(s)? Or do you simply mean your `Route`s are nested more deeply and because of this a single `Switch` won't work? Are you trying declare/use one 404 route, or are more than one acceptable? Do your `buyers` or `dashboard` ids need to wrap where they are?

Comment: When would you show 404 page. Is it when none of the Buyer or Seller Routes match?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper container to render passed children props inside div. For details check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/raghavgarg1257/1ad1eb6a8b61c97e6f107c8c2917fff1)

And to add 404-Not found, this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43284528/7344164) might help.

Comment: There's a typo in that gist. `Container` attempts to destructure a `props` prop from the `props` object. I don't know if that is your gist, but you should test code before you suggest others to use it. Also, if your answer is mostly a link to another SO question/answer then perhaps it would be better to flag this one as a duplicate.

Comment: Ok Thanks. No, that gist is not mine.

Comment: @DevLoverUmar Thanks for your answer, but that didn't help