# wrong React Route Redirect

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

I made an error page and redirect to it if the route is incorrect. But when I open localhost, the main page is error. But I need '/main'

```
 <Route path="/activities/" exact>
</Route>
            <Route path="/error" component={ErrorComponent} />
            <Redirect from="*" to="/error" />
            <Route path="/">
              <Redirect to="/main" />
            </Route>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to move the `<Redirect from="*" to="/error" />` at bottom of all routes and add `exact` in `<Route path="/">`

```
 <Route path="/activities/" exact>
 </Route>
 <Route path="/error" component={ErrorComponent} />
 <Route path="/" exact>
     <Redirect to="/main" />
 </Route>
 <Redirect to="/error" />
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37491381/7412827) will also help you in redirecting to the error route

Answer (score 2):

The wildcard redirect `<Redirect from="*" to="/error" />` is being called first and causes any route to be redirected to your `<Route path="/error" component={ErrorComponent} />` route

Wrap your `<Route />` and `<Redirect />` components in a `<Switch>` component as follows:

```
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router";

<Switch>
  <Route path="/activities/" exact />
  <Route path="/error" component={ErrorComponent} exact />
  <Route path="/main" exact />
  <Redirect from="/" to="/main" />
  <Redirect from="*" to="/error" />
</Switch>
```

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch