# Why isn't the custom 404 page being used in my React app?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

The following code is App.js for React's SPA. I am using react-router-dom v5 to set up a 404 page, but it shows a default 404.

What is wrong with my code?

```js
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import ScrollToTop from '../src/pages/ScrollToTop.js'
import Header from "../src/pages/Header.js"
import Footer from "../src/pages/Footer.js"
import Top from '../src/pages/Top.js'
import Salon from '../src/pages/Salon.js'
// Redux
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import store from '../src/store/redux.js'

function App() {  
  return (
    // ログインしているユーザーの情報を全ページに渡している。
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <ScrollToTop />
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/salon/:uid' component={Salon} />
          <Route exact path='/salon/:uid/:tag' component={Salon} />
          <Route exact path='/' component={Top} />
          <Route path='/*'><NoMatch /></Route>
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  )
}

function NoMatch() {
  let location = useLocation();

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        No match for <code>{location.pathname}</code>
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

Comment: For example, /a, /xxx,/5, etc.

Comment: When viewed locally, NotMatch is displayed, but when deployed, the default is displayed...
It is not a cache issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Router: No Not Found Route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128978/react-router-no-not-found-route)

Comment: I have tried without slash, but the situation remains the same.

Comment: I don't see any overt issue with your code here. You say it works locally, as one would expect, but that it's not working when deployed. What investigation/debugging have you done? Where is the app deployed? Are the other `"/salon/XXXX"` routes working when deployed?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of displaying the component `NoMatch` as a child to `Route`, you can give it as a props:

```
<Route path='*' element={NoMatch} />
```

But actually I can't reproduce your issue, since when I copy your code in codesandbox, it is working as expected. Could you please try to provide a small reproducible example?

Comment: When viewed locally, NotMatch is displayed, but when deployed, the default is displayed... It is not a cache issue

Answer (score -1):

```
<Route path='/salon/:uid' component={Salon} />
<Route path='/salon/:uid/:tag' component={Salon} />
<Route  path='/' component={Top} />
<Route path='*'><NoMatch /></Route>
```

Comment: It will always meet the condition of the 3rd route here. You have to specify that it has to be exact, so it matches the 3rd route only if the url has just one slash